# Como fazer um contador regressivo com javascript?

Tags: javascript, cookies, onclick, countdown

Olá gente eu não entendo praticamente nada de Javascript, então há semanas eu estava tentando fazer um script que fizesse o seguinte:

```
                                  00:00:00
```

1º começasse uma contagem regressiva de 20 minutos depois que clicasse num link.

2º E no mesmo tempo redirecionasse para um site.

3º ao passar os 20 minutos o relógio ficaria no zero assim 00:00:00 para que o 
usuário clicasse e começasse a contagem novamente e redirecionasse para o site pós click.

(Lembrado que redireciona após o clique e não após terminar a contagem!)

4º E que tivesse cookies para que continuasse a contagem mesmo após atualizar a página!

Eu não consegui fazer isso, mas eu achei um script que faz quase tudo listado acima. O único problema do script é que ele não tem o link para clicar e começar a contagem e nem tem o código de cookies para continuar mesmo após atualizar a página!
Vejam o código abaixo e se souberem me digam o que posso fazer para colocar o link para ser clicado e o código de cookies

```html
<html><head> <script language="javaScript"> 
 var min, seg;  min = 20;  seg = 1  
 function relogio(){   
  if((min > 0) || (seg > 0)){    
   if(seg == 0){     
    seg = 59;     
    min = min - 1 
   }    
   else{     
    seg = seg - 1;    
   }    
   if(min.toString().length == 1){     
    min = "0" + min;    
   }    
   if(seg.toString().length == 1){     
    seg = "0" + seg;    
   }    
   document.getElementById('spanRelogio').innerHTML = min + ":" + seg;    
   setTimeout('relogio()', 1000);   
  }   
  else{    
   document.getElementById('spanRelogio').innerHTML = "00:00";   
  }  
 } 
</script></head><body style="font-family:verdana;font-size:10px;" onLoad="relogio()"> <span id="spanRelogio"></span></body></html>
```

---

Gente eu dei uma mudada no script e conseguir colocar o link, mas acontece que depois que termina a contagem ele fica travado no 00:00 ese clicar de novo não recomeça a contagem (mudei para 1 minuto para ser mais rapido) vejam↓

```html
  <script language="javaScript"> 
   var min, seg;  min = 1;  seg = 1  
   function relogio(){   
    if((min > 0) || (seg > 0)){    
     if(seg == 0){     
      seg = 59;     
      min = min - 1 
     }    
     else{     
      seg = seg - 1;    
     }    
     if(min.toString().length == 1){     
      min = "0" + min;    
     }    
     if(seg.toString().length == 1){     
      seg = "0" + seg;    
     }    
     document.getElementById('spanRelogio').innerHTML = min + ":" + seg;    
     setTimeout('relogio()', 1000);   
    }   
    else{    
     document.getElementById('spanRelogio').innerHTML = "00:00";   
    }  
   } 
  </script> 
 <a href="http://pt.stackoverflow.com/" onClick="relogio(event)" target="_blank">Clique Aqui</a>
 
 <span id="spanRelogio"></span>
```

Comment: Muda o "span" para um "a" e poe o "href".. e o problema do link tá resolvido ;)

Comment: Cara eu fiz isso, só que o próprio contador regressivo se tornava o link e também o contador já se iniciava sozinho. Então para que o contador não se tornasse um link eu coloquei o link abaixo dessa forma:                                               <a id="spanRelogio" href="http://pt.stackoverflow.com/" onClick="relogio(event)" target="_blank">Clique Aqui</a>                                       Mas ainda assim o contador começava sozinho faça o teste

Comment: eu tirei o onLoad="relogio() e coloquei <a id="spanRelogio" href="http://pt.stackoverflow.com/" onClick="relogio(event)" target="_blank">Clique Aqui</a>  ta quase do jeito que eu quero :)

Comment: Oi @Marcio.sx sua pergunta foi respondida, deu certo ai?

Answer (score 1):

Fiz algumas alterações no seu código. Dê uma olhada:

**Obs:** Para testar o código. salve o mesmo e teste em seu servidor local. Se não o cookie não irá funcionar!

```html
<script language="javaScript"> 
'use strict'
   var min = 1,
    seg = 1;

   function start() {

    if((min == 1) && (seg == 1)){
     relogio()
    }
   }

   function relogio(){  

    if((min > 0) || (seg > 0)){    
     if(seg == 0){     
      seg = 59;     
      min = min - 1 
     }    
     else{     
      seg = seg - 1;    
     }    
     if(min.toString().length == 1){     
      min = "0" + min;    
     }    
     if(seg.toString().length == 1){     
      seg = "0" + seg;    
     }    
     document.getElementById('spanRelogio').innerHTML = min + ":" + seg;    
     setTimeout('relogio()', 1000);  
     setCookie('tempo',min + ":" + seg,30)
    }   
    else{    
     document.getElementById('spanRelogio').innerHTML = "00:00";  
     min = 1;
     seg = 1; 
    }  
   } 

   function setCookie(cname,cvalue,exdays) {
       var d = new Date();
       d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
       var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
       document.cookie = cname+"="+cvalue+"; "+expires;
   }

   function getCookie(cname) {
       var name = cname + "=";
       var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
       for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
           var c = ca[i];
           while (c.charAt(0)==' ') {
               c = c.substring(1);
           }
           if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
               return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
           }
       }
       return "";
   }

   function checkCookie() {

       var cookie = getCookie("tempo");

       if ( cookie != "" ) {

     var tempo = getCookie('tempo').split(':');
     min = tempo[0];
     seg = tempo[1];

     relogio();
       } 

   }
  </script> 

  <body onload="checkCookie()">
 <a href="http://pt.stackoverflow.com/" onClick="start()" target="_blank">Clique Aqui</a>
 
 <span id="spanRelogio"></span>

 <body>
```

**Explicação:**

Corrigi seu problema de chamar sempre a função relogio(). criei uma função chamada start() que faz uma verificação se a função relogio() ja foi chamada.

Para o uso do cookie, segui a documentação do: [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)

Dê uma olhada no código e qualquer dúvida fique a vontade em perguntar! ;)

Answer (score 1):

```html
   ***** ON Pure javascript *****

function startTimer(duration, display) {
    var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
    setInterval(function () {
        minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

        if (--timer < 0) {
            timer = duration;
        }
    }, 1000);
}

window.onload = function () {
    var fiveMinutes = 60 * 5,
        display = document.querySelector('#time');
    startTimer(fiveMinutes, display);
};




***** On JQUERY *****


function startTimer(duration, display) {
    var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
    setInterval(function () {
        minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        display.text(minutes + ":" + seconds);

        if (--timer < 0) {
            timer = duration;
        }
    }, 1000);
}

jQuery(function ($) {
    var fiveMinutes = 60 * 5,
        display = $('#time');
    startTimer(fiveMinutes, display);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var aa = 2020
var mm = 06
var dd = 07
var hh = 17
var mi = 00

function definircontagemregressiva(ano, mes, dia, horas, minutos) {
  yr = ano;
  mo = mes;
  da = dia
}
definircontagemregressiva(aa, mm, dd)


var ocasiao = "Casamento"
var message_on_ocasiao = "É HOJEEEEEE!!!"


var contagemRegressiva_largura = '510px'
var contagemRegressiva_altura = '200px'
var contagemRegressiva_color = '#ccffe1'
var abrirtags = '<font face="Verdana" size="5" color="#000000">'
var fechartags = '</font>'


var mesArray = new Array("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec")
var contagemcruzada = ''

function start_countdown() {
  if (document.layers)
    document.contadorRegressivo_main.visibility = "show"
  else if (document.all || document.getElementById)
    contagemcruzada = document.getElementById && !document.all ? document.getElementById("countdownie") : countdownie
  countdown()
}

if (document.all || document.getElementById)
  document.write('<span id="countdownie" style="width:' + contagemRegressiva_largura + '; background-color:' + contagemRegressiva_color + '"></span>')

window.onload = start_countdown


function countdown() {
  var today = new Date()
  var todayy = today.getYear()
  if (todayy < 1000)
    todayy += 1900
  var todaym = today.getMonth()
  var todayd = today.getDate()
  var todayh = today.getHours()
  var todaymin = today.getMinutes()
  var todaysec = today.getSeconds()
  var todaystring = mesArray[todaym] + " " + todayd + ", " + todayy + " " + todayh + ":" + todaymin + ":" + todaysec
  futurestring = mesArray[mo - 1] + " " + da + ", " + yr
  dd = Date.parse(futurestring) - Date.parse(todaystring)
  dday = Math.floor(dd / (60 * 60 * 1000 * 24) * 1)
  dhour = Math.floor((dd % (60 * 60 * 1000 * 24)) / (60 * 60 * 1000) * 1)
  dmin = Math.floor(((dd % (60 * 60 * 1000 * 24)) % (60 * 60 * 1000)) / (60 * 1000) * 1)
  dsec = Math.floor((((dd % (60 * 60 * 1000 * 24)) % (60 * 60 * 1000)) % (60 * 1000)) / 1000 * 1)

  //-----------Se no dia da ocasião-----------//

  if (dday <= 0 && dhour <= 0 && dmin <= 0 && dsec <= 1 && todayd == da) {
    if (document.layers) {
      document.contadorRegressivo_main.document.countdownnssub.document.write(abrirtags + message_on_ocasiao + fechartags)
      document.contadorRegressivo_main.document.countdownnssub.document.close()
    } else if (document.all || document.getElementById)
      contagemcruzada.innerHTML = abrirtags + message_on_ocasiao + fechartags
    return
  }

  //---------Se passou dia da ocasião-----------//
  else if (dday <= -1) {
    if (document.layers) {
      document.contadorRegressivo_main.document.countdownnssub.document.write(abrirtags + "ocasiao already passed! " + fechartags)
      document.contadorRegressivo_main.document.countdownnssub.document.close()
    } else if (document.all || document.getElementById)
      contagemcruzada.innerHTM = abrirtags + "Já passou" + fechartags
    return
  }

  //----------Caso contrário, se ainda não-----------//
  else {
    if (document.layers) {
      document.contadorRegressivo_main.document.countdownnssub.document.write(abrirtags + dday + " days, " + dhour + " hours, " + dmin + " minutes, and " + dsec + " " + occasion + closetags)
      document.countdowncontadorRegressivo_mainnsmain.document.countdownnssub.document.close()
    } else if (document.all || document.getElementById)
      contagemcruzada.innerHTML = abrirtags + dday + " dias, " + dhour + " horas, " + dmin + " minutos e " + dsec + " segundos para o <b>" + ocasiao + fechartags
  }
  setTimeout("countdown()", 1000)
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
const daysIni = 2; 
const hoursIni = 23; 
const minutesIni = 59; 
const secondsIni = 59; 

startTimer(daysIni , hoursIni, minutesIni, secondsIni ) {

        let seconds = secondsIni;
        let minutes = minutesIni;
        let hours = hoursIni;
        let days = daysIni;
    
        setInterval(() => { 
          seconds--;
          if (seconds < 0) { 
            seconds = 59; 
            minutes--;
            if (minutes < 0) { 
              minutes = 59; 
              hours--;
              if (hours < 0) { 
                hours = 23; 
                days--;
              }
            }
          }
    
          let timer  = days.toString() + 'dias : ' + hours.toString().padStart(2, '0') + 'hs : ' + minutes.toString().padStart(2, '0') + 'min : ' + seconds.toString().padStart(2, '0') + 's ';
        }, 1000);

          document.getElementById('spanRelogio').innerHTML = timer; 
    
    }
    
    }
```